# Why does JS minification convert 1000 to 1E3?

Tags: javascript, minify

**What is the point** to change *(int)* `1000` to `1E3`?

And where does `1E3` come from?

*I know just `3bytes` vs `4bytes`.*

Comment: 1E3 is notation for the mathematical expression 10^3 which is the same as 1000. If you wrote a million 1E6 would be 1000000 and then you would save two more bytes.

Comment: @mortb "1E6" saves _two_ more bytes compare to what?

Comment: @Cœur yes I was wrong saying "two more bytes". It should be three more bytes. 1000 -> 1E3 saves one byte/character, 1000000 -> saves 1E6 saves four charactes, which is three more bytes.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The whole point of minification is to be able to pass less data over the network but retain the same functionality.

> #### *Taken [from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)):*
>
> Minification (also minimisation or minimization), in computer programming languages and especially JavaScript, is the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code without changing its functionality. These unnecessary characters usually include white space characters, new line characters, comments, and sometimes block delimiters, which are used to add readability to the code but are not required for it to execute.

As long as the size is smaller the minification is doing its job.

`1E3` pretty much means 10 to the power of 3; a shorter way of representing the number 1000.

Comment: I was looking at my code (handling time calculations) wondering why the heck I would have used 1e3 instead of 1000 and realized I was looking at the minified code and not the original source.

Answer (score 14):

they are the same value, 1E3 is 10 to the third power, or 1000, so the point it so save 25%

Comment: [citation needed] :p You and I know that 1E3 is scientific notation for 1000, but perhaps OP does not and that's why the question is being asked ;)

Comment: @PA. can you put any integer BEFORE and AFTER the 'e'? or is it just 1eX?

Comment: @J3STER Yes. `AeB` is `A * 10**B`.

Answer (score 13):

To be precise: `1e3` stands for `1 * 10^3`

Further Examples:
`2e2` = `200` and
`0.1e2` = `10`

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates

Comment: You can also achieve the same result by the infix operator in ES6. `10**3` is `1000` however this doesn't occupy less bytes compared to the `e` notation.